# Is it possible to use a custom shape for proportional editing?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, proportional-editing

I'm trying to add perspective to a picture however, I would like the proportional editing tool to affect only a certain part of the plane I imported. So, is there a way to pull only a specific zone (not a perfect circle), while using the the proportional editing?

Or is there an other way to easily add perspective?

[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: When posting screenshots, try to crop them to the relevant parts only. Otherwise good question, although I doubt it is possible currently.

Comment: How about modeling from scratch like: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/how-would-i-go-about-creating-a-spiralled-dome ?

Answer (score 6):

Another method would be to select all vertices that should not be affected and hide them temporarilly <kbd>H</kbd>.

It could be easier to select the vertices that should be influenced and invert the selection <kbd>I</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't limit the influence of proportional editing to a vertex group. You can achieve this with the *hook modifier*.

Select the vertices that should be influenced and assign them to a vertex group:

[image]
[image]

Setup the modifier like this:

This would create a plateau on the top, when you're happy with the border use *proportional editing* to deform the top to a sphere:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but that doesn't produce what I need.  Your solution gives a flat top, but what I need is a round snail... What I would need is to select the region and only influence this region with the proportional editing

Comment: you could stil to combine both techniques first use the hook followed by proportional editing. Post updated.

Comment: Hum...  The selected region would then need to be smaller then the real object to uprise, since the hook modifyer will drag vertices in the near region...  I'll try.  By the way, I will add the original picture so you will be able to try for yourself...