# How can I make an indented cube without using a boolean operation?

Tags: modeling, mesh

As the title says, how can I make this shape without resorting to a Boolean operation?

[image: Cube Cut Out]

This is obviously a very simple example, but I find myself needing to do something like this relatively often when modelling.

Despite using Blender for a couple of years, and considering myself an intermediate to possibly advanced user, I still know of no easy way to make this kind of indentation in an object.

Obviously, if you are looking to make an indentation in the middle of the surface, you can simply select a face and extrude down. As you will know, this does not work at the edge of the surface.

I can create this shape using loop cuts, deleting the faces and then using snap to edge to extrude the edges down to the same level (and then filling in the faces), but it feels cumbersome and a lot of work for what feels like it should be very simple.

Comment: The most efficient in Blender is planning ahead. Changing things always results in many many clicks. In the past Blender modeling workflow was top-notch, but it is destructive and nowadays it doesn't keep up with the industry (imho).

Comment: Still quite like blender hotkey driven workflow, I feel it is quite fluid, though I know where you are coming from. More procedural or non destructive tools are highly desirable.

Comment: While I agree with Jerryno that planning ahead is generally the best policy, I would further note that I have found that if changes do have to be made, it is preferable to have the changes be additive, rather than subtractive. However, in my view, this question is both too broad, and too much a matter of opinion to be within scope of Blender Stack Exchange, and would be best be asked in a forum such as may be found at Blender Artist.com. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @brasshat You can obviously vote to close if you wish, but i disagree with your comment. The question relates to what tools are available in Blender and the best kind of workflow. It isn't opinion based, and meets the guidelines. I see neither how that can be "too broad", nor how "you need to plan ahead" is very useful advice in this context.

Comment: We actually have quite a few of these ["best way"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=best+way) posts. For the better or more interesting ones, I like to see them as fun challenges to see a variety of methods to go about a task, example http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2297/12 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5623/12. So this fine to me other than the specific subjective title. Feel free to bring this up on meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would also like to know a faster method than this, though this is the best I could come up with.

1. Select All faces <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*
2. Select the middle edgeloop and bevel as desired
3. Extrude upper or frontal face and snap in position
4. Delete the two remaining undesired faces, then *Remove Doubles*

[image: Cube]

Comment: I think Duarte's solution is the best way to do it. You may do it using a Solidify modifier though, but the edge flow after applying it won't allow you to crease the mesh's edges properly.

Comment: That's a variation on what I am currently doing, but probably marginally quicker. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

The F2 addon is quite useful for operations like this.

Make sure it is enabled in user preferences, then...

1. Delete the faces where you want the indentation.
2. Select an outer corner vertex and press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face.
3. Repeat 2 for the other corner vertex.
4. Select the upper (or lower) edge.
5. Press <kbd>F</kbd> twice to fill in the remaining faces.

[image: F2 usage example]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the cool [addon](https://gumroad.com/l/cQjUX#)

Download and Install its FREE

No need of deleting extra face or remove double, etc

Just make a cube sub divide the cube. Select multiple faces. Press Alt+E and select Destructive Extrude option and just push the face up or down or with the holding ctrl key we can align with the edges.

[image]