# Fill a solid corner topologically correct

Tags: mesh

When constructing technical objects I often come to a point where I want to add something into a corner. I haven't found an easy way to do so in a topologically correct way.

As a simple example this would be the situation with the corner to be filled
[image]

And this is the target to be achieved:
[image]

Given how easy it is to extrude such a block, I wonder if there is no easy way here as well.

Solutions I've tried so far:

- extrude one of the two adjacent faces -> this gives a topologically incorrect model which causes problems later on
- add a cube of the desired size, and make a boolean union -> (almost) impossible to avoid creating small steps and quite cumbersome
- extrude one edge and fill the three faces manually afterwards. -> this is topologically correct, but still a bit cumbersome
- isn't there an easier way???

Comment: You might pick up a thing or two from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76521/how-can-i-make-an-indented-cube-without-using-a-boolean-operation

Comment: Very much related: [Make quad face from where two edges will meet?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42014/2217)

Comment: Possible dup https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42014/2217

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have F2 addon enabled, here is a very magical trick.

Pressing F when F2 is enabled, several things will happen:

1. If 1 vertex is selected, it will create a face from the 2 edges connected with the vertex in the direction/position of the mouse cursor.
2. If 2 vertices or an edge is selected, it will try to created a quad face with the adjacent edges/vertices.  And the result doesn't need merging or 'remove double'.
3. If 3 or more edges are selected, it will simply create a face with selected edges.  Result can be an N-gon.

[image]

Comment: That's indeed a very magical and helpful trick! Thanks :)

Comment: @derHugo, thanks to the developers of the F2 addon.  It's such a nice feature.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried some methods with *Bridge Edge Loops*, *Grid Fill* and such, but I think that the fastest way would be this one:

[image: steps]

1. Remove corner **Edge**.
2. Select **Edges** around one corner wall.
3. Turn on **Snapping to Vertex**.
4. **Extrude** along needed axis - <kbd>E</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd> in this example.
5. Create **Face** - <kbd>F</kbd>.
6. **Select all** (<kbd>A</kbd>) and <kbd>W</kbd> > **Remove Doubles**.

Comment: nice trick to plan ahead using "Remove Doubles". But the F2 addon from @TeaCrab seems not only faster, but also more versatile (works as well for example if extrude is not along an axis).

Comment: The method @LukeD provided can be useful when the geometry isn't simply 3 missing faces.  His method is much more efficient when there are a number of edges along a hole, F2 in that case will be a bit of headache.