# Is there a way to extrude in a smart way?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Is there an easier way to extrude models a certain way

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe this title is a bit misleading and doesn't really match the body of the question. "*Non Destructive*" is a term often used to describe modelling using non permanent solutions or techniques involving modifiers, node based setups or other procedural tools. This is just not the result you expect. See possible duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76521/how-can-i-make-an-indented-cube-without-using-a-boolean-operation/

Comment: You can find the smart extrude functionality in software like SketchUp or Zbrush. Not in vanilla Blender though, you will need to use different tools or more editing steps to get the result, or use addons like [this one](https://gumroad.com/l/cQjUX#)

Comment: If someone still needs an answer
Here the addon that does it (extrude like sketchup) https://github.com/capnm/b8ExtrudePull

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there's no magic button (like <kbd>E</kbd>) to extrude the way you want.

The simplest/fastest way I know is using *Loop Cut and Slide* in Face/Edge-edit mode (see picture).

[image: Face/Edge-edit mode]

It can become a very fast operation, if you get into the habit (see GIFs below).
Basically you use loop cut and slide to create faces where you need them and then you just move your face (instead of extruding it).

[image]

In this first situation I'm just hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to start the "Loop Cut and Slide" command, I create one edge in the face and I slide it to the border, do the same in the other direction (to the other edge), then I select the face and I move it on the Z axis.

[image]

And here I'm doing the same but I do just one cut and slide it to the lower edge.