# How not to have a face left over when extruding a face inwards?

Tags: faces, extrude

Here's a screenshot showcasing my problem:

[image]

I found [some resources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=359&v=MjhiP8eFL3o) on this issue, but for some reason, it's not working for me. I'm using the Inset tool, and setting the depth to a negative number.

Do I need edge loops first for that to work? There's no way for blender to create vertices at the right spot automatically?

Comment: Please look at the [2nd answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92842/30849).

Comment: this Push/Push Extrude operation will soon be implemented in Blender

Comment: I believe destructive extruding will come in 2.90 (it's an [often requested feature](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Qlcbbc/)), so perhaps August 2020?

Comment: Ok, great to hear it's coming to Blender!

@Leander cool, but it's only for 2.79, not 2.8, correct? Otherwise that'd be exactly what Im looking for indeed.

Comment: I found [this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/destructive-extrude-beta/678275/311), maybe there is the updated addon. Didn't read it, downloaded a version, didn't work, did a quick fix for 2.82. You can download it [here from my github](https://github.com/LeanderSilur/Blender-Tools/raw/master/destructive_extrude.zip) if you can't wait till August =) Quick test seemed to look ok, message me if it messes up.